How to apply Pohlig Hellman using a very limited set of auxiliary inputs in that case?
So I was reading about Talotti, Paier, and Miculan - ECC’s Achilles’ Heel: Unveiling Weak Keys in Standardized Curves. The underlying idea is to lift the discrete logarithm problem to $\mathrm{prime}−1$ for prime curves or $\mathrm{order}−1$ for binary curves without using auxiliary inputs at all since most elliptic curves only have small factors in that case. But their baby‑step giant‑step variant seems to only work when the private key already lie in a specific subgroup. That is : no indication is made on how to move the key to each underlying order subgroup. And of course, using exponentiations to solve the problem isn’t a reason that allow building an index calculus algorithm…
If I understand correctly (or maybe I’m wrong), being able to use Pohlig Hellman would require using auxiliary inputs as proposed by Cheon : but in my case, I only have 48 of them over the extension of a pairing friendly curve of large characteristic.
As a related problem, would it be possible to create a $p+1$ variant without using auxiliary inputs?
